# Javascript 'node' vscode... Not Working... But no folder C:\Program Files\nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm a **beginner** to **JavaScript** and I'm trying to run it on **Visual Studio Code.**
This is my code :

```
console.log('hello world'.toUpperCase());  //yes, only one line...
```

But this **error** is showing up every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (I use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)):

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\TheCoder\Desktop\script.js"
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.027 seconds
```

After seeing some other StackOverflow answers, I've looked on to going to **Environment Variables** and adding `C:\Program Files\nodejs;` to  `PATH`, but there is no folder (or file) such as `C:\Program Files\nodejs;` or  `C:\Program Files(x86)\nodejs;` .

Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Well, did you actually install Node.js?

Comment: Did you install node via nvm???

Comment: yes I did install Node.js But not with nvm

Comment: does `node -v` work in cmd?

Comment: @avc Where did you install nodejs to when you ran the installer?

Comment: Thanks @iconfig I had installed it at the wrong place ;)